# github issue feedback like on microsoft docs

Tags: github, issue-tracking, github-issues

When you go to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/aspnet/core/getting-started/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=macos for example, or any other microsoft docs, and the end of the page there is github feedback - you can open an issue directly on the site or on guthub, as the docs are published on github.

I want to do something like this for my website, where people reading articles can suggest improvements. This is a good way to make a wiki like site. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: There are likely out of the box plug-ins depending on your platform.  I would recommend writing it from scratch so you can customise it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want a URL for opening a blank issue, all you need is to provide a link to `https://github.com/<user-name>/<repo-name>/issues/new`.

If you want the issue to have prefilled text, you can use query parameters to generate the URL. [This help page](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/about-automation-for-issues-and-pull-requests-with-query-parameters) describes how this can be done.

The easy way would be to create an issue template on GitHub, and then use the `template` parameter. As [quoted](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-your-work-on-github/about-automation-for-issues-and-pull-requests-with-query-parameters#filling-issues-and-pull-requests-with-custom-templates) in the linked article:

> You can use the template query parameter to specify a template to automatically fill the issue or pull request body. The template query parameter works with templates stored in an ISSUE_TEMPLATE or PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE subdirectory within the root, docs/ or .github/ directory in a repository.
>
> If a repository contains only the default pull request or issue template, any new issues or pull requests will have the default template in the body.

You can also use the other parameters to customize the issue title, text, labels, etc. [This project](https://github.com/sindresorhus/new-github-issue-url) slightly simplifies this task.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your answers, but I found this https://utteranc.es/ and its everything I wanted. And its easy to use. I will leave the other for the right answer, but if someone wants something more out of the box you can use my finding.